# Don't know how to display error when using foreach

Tags: php, arrays, loops, model-view-controller, foreach

I'm working (for the firs time) with MVC model and I'm having some problems when displaying the errors warnings...

For example I got this

Controller:

```
include_once(UserModel.php);

$userdata = new User_Model();
$biography = $userdata->Get_UserBio();
```

Model:

```
include_once(conexion.php);

                //I make my prepared query and...
                if ($user_infoprofile->execute()):

                    $data= $user_infoprofile->get_result();

                    if ($data->num_rows):
                        while ($result=$data->fetch_array()):
                        $this->userbio[]=$result;
                        endwhile;
                    else:
                         //I want to display something like
                         $error= "you have to fill your bio",
                         echo $error;
                    endif;
                else:
                    $error="invalid request";
                    echo $error;
                endif;
                return $this->userbio;
                $user_infoprofile->close();
```

View:

```
include_once(UserController.php);

//if there are rows in the array I display

foreach...

//But heres my problem... if there are not rows in the array... I want to display something else
```

How can I do it? I'm kind of beginner on this, or is there any other more clean way to do it?

Comment: One small mistake
 $error= "you have to fill your bio", here you ended with comma, just end with semicolon and try

Answer (score 0):

Use quotes in your `require` functions. Like this : `include_once('UserModel.php');`. If you want to display all errors, you can do it with this lines :

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(empty($var_array)){
echo "There is not results...";
        }else{
foreach....
        }
```

Do you mean how to check if the array is empty?

Comment: Check what values gets $data, because if u select does not retrieve anythim, the $data gonna be empty

Comment: I mean how to fill the array with a warning message in case the query doesnt find any rows so in that way I can display the message to the user using foreach too

Comment: Something like that? assing the value to the array var,
else:
//I want to display something like
$this->userbio[]="you have to fill your bio";
echo $error;
endif;

Answer (score -1):

ok but, the problem is how to doit in a specific part of my view.php file... because If I use 'echo' this message will appear anywhere and not where I would want to...